# Swift Thread Issue

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch

I have a thread issue that prevent me to execute a function that takes as parameter a struct and returns the same struct but with an address variable as `CLLocation` instead `String`. My issue is that every time the function is called the code inside the closure is executed after the return statement. Does anyone knows how to fix it?

```
private func setOriginCompany(from data: JourneyAPI) -> WendaCompany {
    var company = WendaCompany(id: "unknown", name: "unknown", street: "unknown", streetNumber: "unknown", city: "unknown", postalCode: 00000, region: "unknown", nationality: "unknown", latitude: 00, longitude: 00, phone: nil, email: nil, note: nil, products: nil)
    guard let originName = data.OriginName else { return company }
    guard let originAddress = data.OriginAddress else { return company}
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.addressToCoordinates(address: originAddress) { (completion) in
            switch completion {
                case .success(let resultCompany):
                    company = resultCompany
                    company.name = originName
                
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("\nERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)\n")
            }
        }
    }
    
    return company
}
```

This is what happen inside the `addressToCoordinates` method:

```
private func coordinatesToAddress(location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    var company: WendaCompany!
    
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { [weak self] (placemarks, error) in
        guard self != nil else { return }

        if error != nil {
            return
        }

        guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
            //TODO: Show alert to user somethign went wrong
            return
        }
        guard let placemarkStreet = placemark.thoroughfare else { return }
        guard let placemarkStreetNumber = placemark.subThoroughfare else { return }
        guard let placemarkCity = placemark.locality else { return }
        guard let placemarkRegion = placemark.administrativeArea else { return }
        guard let placemarkNationality = placemark.country else { return }
        guard let placemarkPostalCode = placemark.postalCode else { return }
        guard let placemarkLatitude = placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude else { return }
        guard let placemarkLongitude = placemark.location?.coordinate.longitude else { return }
        
        company = WendaCompany(id: UUID().uuidString,
                               name: "unknonw",
                               street: placemarkStreet,
                               streetNumber: placemarkStreetNumber,
                               city: placemarkCity,
                               postalCode: (placemarkPostalCode as NSString).integerValue,
                               region: placemarkRegion,
                               nationality: placemarkNationality,
                               latitude: placemarkLatitude,
                               longitude: placemarkLongitude,
                               phone: nil, email: nil, note: nil, products: nil)
        
    })

}
```

Comment: "the closure is executed after the return statement. " Because it's asynchrone. That's the concept you are missing. You noticed it (good point, a lot of beginner didn't).

Comment: @Larme So I just need to change from async to sync and then would be good?

Answer (score 0):

as @larme said
"The closure is executed after the return statement. " Because it's asynchronous. That's the concept you are missing. You noticed it (good point, a lot of beginners didn't).

replace this method

```
private func setOriginCompany(from data: JourneyAPI) -> WendaCompany {
    var company = WendaCompany(id: "unknown", name: "unknown", street: "unknown", streetNumber: "unknown", city: "unknown", postalCode: 00000, region: "unknown", nationality: "unknown", latitude: 00, longitude: 00, phone: nil, email: nil, note: nil, products: nil)
    guard let originName = data.OriginName else { return company }
    guard let originAddress = data.OriginAddress else { return company}
    
    
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.addressToCoordinates(address: originAddress) { (completion) in
            switch completion {
                case .success(let resultCompany):
                    company = resultCompany
                    company.name = originName
                
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("\nERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)\n")
            }
        }
    }
    
    return company
}
```

with this one:

```
var company = WendaCompany(id: "unknown", name: "unknown", street: "unknown", streetNumber: "unknown", city: "unknown", postalCode: 00000, region: "unknown", nationality: "unknown", latitude: 00, longitude: 00, phone: nil, email: nil, note: nil, products: nil)

private func setOriginCompany(from data: JourneyAPI) -> WendaCompany {
    
    guard let originName = data.OriginName else { return }
    guard let originAddress = data.OriginAddress else { return }
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.addressToCoordinates(address: originAddress) { (completion) in
            switch completion {
                case .success(let resultCompany):
                    self.company = resultCompany
                    self.company.name = originName
                
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("\nERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)\n")
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This is not the best solution with a struct. The property is accessed from two different threads which will lead to racing conditions. Better use a completion handler.

Comment: Like what could you be more specific? 
Because I spent quite time trying solving this inconvenience and as you can see I still struggle with some concept therefore if you would so kind to provide me with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `return` a value from a method that is running asynchronously. So, instead, adopt an asynchronous pattern, namely a completion handler closure. E.g.:

```
private func setOriginCompany(from data: JourneyAPI, completion: @escaping (Result<WendaCompany, Error>) -> Void) {
    var company = WendaCompany(id: "unknown", name: "unknown", street: "unknown", streetNumber: "unknown", city: "unknown", postalCode: 00000, region: "unknown", nationality: "unknown", latitude: 00, longitude: 00, phone: nil, email: nil, note: nil, products: nil)
    guard 
        let originName = data.OriginName,
        let originAddress = data.OriginAddress 
    else {
        return company
    }
    
    addressToCoordinates(address: originAddress) { (completion) in
        switch completion {
            case .success(let resultCompany):
                company = resultCompany
                company.name = originName
                completion(.success(company))
            
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}
```

and you'd call it like so:

```
setOriginCompany(from: data) { result in 
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error): 
        print(error)

    case .success(let company):
        // do something with `company` here
    }
}

// but don't try to use it here, because the value hasn't been retrieved yet
```

Note:

1. We're not `return`ing anything.
2. You don't need that dispatch queue. The method you're calling is already asynchronous, so the additional `async` call is redundant and incorrect.
3. You don't need multiple `guard` statements. Just use one with commas separating the various tests.
4. I didn’t fix it here, but I’d advise against a routine that returns an invalid `WendaCompany` model object if, for example, the `originName` or `originAddress` couldn’t be unwrapped. I would personally return a `.failure` with an error rather than `.success` with a bogus model object.